# Does it make sense in English?

Tags: non-native-english

The sentence is "I can't picture playing without putting my middle finger on W" and I'm talking about playing video games on pc.

Comment: Not quite sure why "W", but it makes perfect sense from a language standpoint.

Comment: @HotLicks lol they were talking about playing PUBG mobile and i was just like that... U know i cant do it without a real keyboard

Comment: @HotLicks tnx for the comment btw :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I can't picture" is an idiom meaning "I cannot imagine".